# Run a specific task in a specific date/time . (flutter_background_service)

Tags: flutter

How i schedule that specific service to run in a specific date/time ?

Even if the app is closed .
Im using flutter_background_service with foreground task .

```
await service.configure(
        androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
          onStart: onStart,
          autoStart: true,
          isForegroundMode: true,
          notificationChannelId: 'my_foreground',
          initialNotificationTitle: 'AWESOME SERVICE',
          initialNotificationContent: 'Initializing',
          foregroundServiceNotificationId: 888,
        ),
        iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(
          autoStart: true,
          onForeground: (params) async {
            //await onStart;
          },
        ),
```

I've tried this but nothing :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  int? desiredDateTime = prefs.getInt('selectedDateTime');
  print(desiredDateTime);

  if (desiredDateTime != null) {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    DateTime desiredTime = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day,
        desiredDateTime ~/ 60, desiredDateTime % 60);
    Duration delay = desiredTime.difference(now);

    //Schedule theis  background task at the desired time
    await Timer(delay, () async {
      await service.configure(
        androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
          onStart: onStart,
          autoStart: true,
          isForegroundMode: true,
          notificationChannelId: 'my_foreground',
          initialNotificationTitle: 'AWESOME SERVICE',
          initialNotificationContent: 'Initializing',
          foregroundServiceNotificationId: 888,
        ),
        iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(
          autoStart: true,
          onForeground: (params) async {
            //await onStart;
          },
        ),
      );
    });
  } else {
    print("No selected time found in SharedPreferences.");
  }
```

I get my datetime from a user input.

Answer (score 0):

To schedule a specific service to run at a specific date and time, even when the app is closed, you have to use platform-specific features for background tasks. you can use plugins like **flutter_local_notifications** along with **android_alarm_manager** or **workmanager** for Android and **flutter_workmanager** for iOS.

Here's a general outline of how you can achieve this:

1. **Schedule the Task:** When the user selects a date and time for the
   task to run, save this information (date/time) in persistent storage
   like SharedPreferences or any other preferred method.
2. **Background Task Management:** Implement background task management
   using plugins like android_alarm_manager or workmanager for Android
   and flutter_workmanager for iOS. These plugins allow you to schedule
   tasks that run even when the app is closed.
3. **Execute Task:** In the background task, retrieve the scheduled date
   and time from persistent storage and execute the desired task at
   that specific time.

Here's a simplified example:

```
// Assuming you have already scheduled a notification at a specific time
// Save the scheduled time in SharedPreferences
saveScheduledTime(int selectedDateTime) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setInt('selectedDateTime', selectedDateTime);
}

// Function to execute when the scheduled time is reached
void myBackgroundTask() {
  // Your task logic here
}

// Schedule the background task
scheduleBackgroundTask() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  int? desiredDateTime = prefs.getInt('selectedDateTime');

  if (desiredDateTime != null) {
    // Schedule the background task to execute at the desired time
    await yourBackgroundTaskPlugin.scheduleTask(desiredDateTime, myBackgroundTask);
  } else {
    print("No selected time found in SharedPreferences.");
  }
}
```

Don't forget to handle edge cases such as the scheduled time being in the past when the app is opened again.